# How to get all input value from current active Carousel after click on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap for implementing the carousel. And In the carousel I have some information Like first name, Last Name and address. Information may be more and less. These will be First name also and First name, Last Name and Address also. In the carousel I have one submit button also. On click on submit button I want to get all input value from the child div.

```js
$('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active')
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var ele = $('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active');
    
})
```

```css
.carousel-caption{
  position:static !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="A" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="B" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active text-center">
          <h1>
          John
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="margin-top:30px;">
            <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
           
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item text-center">
            <h1>
          Amreo
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
             <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
           <div>
           Address:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item text-center">
            <h1>
          Kajuiew
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>
       
       
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/hnwyqu3v/20/

How can I fetch all records in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("input").each(function(){
        // Code here
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

In case, you only want to access the element of the parent button clicked, otherwise you can do same trick with `$(".carousel-inner .item.active")` like the answer of @harshit-gupta

```js
$('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active')
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var ele = $('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li.active');
    console.log('target: ' + ele.data('target') + 
                ' value: ' + ele.data('value') + 
                ' slide-to: ' + ele.data('slideTo'));
})

$("button").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().find("input").each(function(){
   // Code here
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
  
});
```

```css
.carousel-caption{
  position:static !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="A" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="B" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-value="C" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active text-center">
          <h1>
          Maria
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="margin-top:30px;">
            <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
           
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item text-center">
            <h1>
          Maron
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
             <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
           <div>
           Address:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item text-center">
            <h1>
          sharon
          </h1>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div>
             Fiirst Name:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
            </div>
          <div>
           LastName:<input type="text" style="color:#000">
          </div>
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
            </div>
             <button type="btn btn-sm button">submit</button>
        </div>
       
       
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add respective classes on the inputs on place of `.first-name` and `.last-name` and use the following code

```
$('#myCarousel').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var parent = $(e.target).parents('.item')
  var firstname = parent.find('.first-name').val();
  var lastname = parent.find('.last-name').val();
  console.log(firstname, lastname)
})
```

Also I've update the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/r3c8z5an/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use each and fetch all the values

```
$('.carousel-inner').find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val()
})
```

hope this helps

Comment: It will give all values, Who has activ and none active carousel

Comment: Try this

$('.carousel-inner div.active').find('input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.item.active').find('input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

It finds all the input fields in the active carousel item (where apparently the  submit button would be clicked).